# Use one repo as the base of others

Tags: git, github

I need to have one master project and if this one have changes, then push this changes to others projects.

**My idea:**

Have 1 master project, named "basic" and "project1", "project2" as a clone of "basic". This clone i created using remote refs in "basic" to each project.

**The problem:**

When i edit some project and then i push from basic to each project, git tell me that i have to do a pull from my project, but i dont want to do it.

**My questions:**

There are a correct way to do somthing like this?
or
What about sending pull request from basic to each project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When i edit some project and then i push from basic to each project, git tell me that i have to do a pull from my project, but i dont want to do it.

There is always a `git push --force` if you really want to. But note that could be harmful if there are other changes in the other projects.

> There are a correct way to do somthing like this? or What about sending pull request from basic to each project?

Creating pull requests should be fine. You should [check the docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request) how to use the GitHub API to create pull requests.

You can also make `git pull` which will also merge the changes (like the pull requests do).

Comment: There is a way to add remote refs to all new projects? because adding remote refs for doing pull or getting for a pull request, it can be some difficult for users without  experience. And in this case, it would be more restricted, giving me more control using push from the master.

Comment: @MateoMarconi I am not sure what you mean. You can add more remotes to the same repository using `git remote add <name> <url>`.